# What do you need to do trigonometry on a space?

Tags: trigonometry

What axioms does a space need to satisfy for trigonometric functions to behave normally on it?

For example, you need a topology to have limits on a space. What do you need for trig?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "behave normally", but a scalar product is enough to define cosine on a vector space.

Comment: Trigonometry makes sense when you have “length” and “angle” in your hand. These concepts can be generalised in a vector space by defining the inner product.